# ftrace + addr2line

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to get kernel source code file name and line number of a kernel function from the function address that `ftrace` outputted on Raspberry Pi 3.

I tried `addr2line -e /boot/kernel8.img [function address]` on Raspberry Pi 3. But it returned `addr2line: /boot/kernel8.img: File format not recognized`.

Note:

`kernel8.img` is customed kernel that I compiled. I cloned kernel source from `https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git`, checkouted to `rpi-4.18.y`, turned on `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`, and run `make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- -j4`. This compile work performed on Ubuntu x86_64 linux kernel 4.15.0-23-generic. The type of `kernel8.img` is as follows.

```
$ file kernel8.img
kernel8.img: MS-DOS executable
```